# How to check that a path has a sticky bit in python?

Tags: python

How to check with python if a path has the sticky bit set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os
def is_sticky(path):
    return os.stat(path).st_mode & 01000 == 01000
```

Answer (score 2):

[os.stat()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) will return a tupple of information about the file.  The first item will be the mode.  You would then be able to use some bit arithmetic to get for the sticky bit.  The sticky bit has an octal value of 1000.