# Portable way of determining if a process can move/delete a file?

Tags: python, linux, macos

What would be a portable way to determine if a Python process can move/delete a file **without** having to move/delete the file in question?

**Use case:** I'd like to inform the user of a script whether or not *move/delete* operations will succeed/fail prior to starting processing.

If there is a solution that only works in Linux, I'd be OK with that for the moment.

Thanks.

**update:** I understand that *os.access* can be used but is limited to real uid/gid.

Comment: Not sure that you're using the security model correctly but interested anyway. The only canonical implementation for this I've seen is inside the kernel, I'm not sure that it's exposed anyway, and to do so is encouraging the wrong kind of programming.

Comment: There's something not quite right about putting "man access" into Google...

Comment: Maybe `bool(os.stat(filepath).st_mode & stat.S_IWGRP)`?

Comment: You say portable. But you include the Linux tag. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @David: forgot the OSX tag...

Answer (score 1):

Would opening the file for append work?

```
try:
    open(filename,'a').close()
```

...and catch any exception indicating that failed?

Use with caution, I'm really not sure that wouldn't do anything nasty by mistake.  For example at least temporarily you'll have locked the file, and I don't know what that would do to a binary file.

Comment: If you can append to a file, but not write to the directory it is in, you can't delete or move it.

Comment: Good point.  You could also try creating and deleting a temp file in the directory.  All this seems quite clumsy to me, admittedly, but it's not os specific at least.

Comment: Hmm, this creating/deleting idea seems more fool proof and 'portable' (although it is ugly). I suggest you edit your answer and put this in. Only thing remaining would be handling the directory sticky bit on UNIXes.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, three conditions need to be met for this on UNIXes:

1. User can write to directory containing the original file (for deletion or move)
2. If the directory containing the original file has the sticky bit set, the original file should be owned by the user (for deletion or move)
3. In case of a move, additionally, The user can write to the directory where it should be moved to

In python, conditions 1 and 3 can be tested with [os.access](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.access#os.access) and condition 2 with os.stat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418204/how-to-check-that-a-path-has-a-sticky-bit-in-python) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html).

**update:** If you want to work with effective UID, then use `os.geteuid()` and interpret `stat` results to check for 1 and 3 as well.